# How to filter select-box in devextreme

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some problems to filter with 03 select boxes, country, state and city.
How can I  get select boxes nested? 
And How can I  get some filter with these data?

My code in script.js using MySQL Database:

```
var serviceFilterCountry = "http://localhost:8000/filtercountry";
var serviceFilterProvince = "http://localhost:8000/filterprovince";
var serviceFilterCity = "http://localhost:8000/filtercity";


$scope.countries = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(serviceFilterCountry);
$scope.provinces = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(serviceFilterProvince);
$scope.cities = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(serviceFilterCity);

//var dataSourceCity = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(serviceFilterCity);

//var dataSourceF = new DevExpress.data.DataSource(serviceFilter);



      $scope.selectedProvince = null;
      $scope.filterProvincesByCountry = function(e) {
        var countryP = e.value;
        $scope.provinces.filter("country", countryP);
        $scope.provinces.load().done(function(result) {
          $scope.selectedProvince = result.state;
        });

      };




      $scope.selectedCity = null;
      $scope.filterCitiesByProvince = function(e) {
        var provinceC = e.value;
        $scope.cities.filter("country", $scope.countries.select('country'));
        $scope.cities.filter("state", provinceC);

        $scope.cities.load().done(function(result) {
          $scope.selectedCity = result.city;
        });

      };
```

Comment: question is really unclear!..you have three select boxes thats all anyone can understand from the question. You said you want to nest them? how can you get some filter to these data? wat filter are you talking about?

Comment: are you saying you want to populate second select based on the select of the country?

Comment: That is really unclear. That is it! How can I load results based on the selected country and/or how should i populate city based on the selected province or state? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter data by a selectbox value you can use the [onValueChanged](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/Configuration/?version=15_1#onValueChanged) event. For example, the following code shows how to filter cities by country id:

JS:

```
$scope.countries = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: [{id: 1, text: "USA"}, {id: 2, text: "Canada"}]
});
$scope.cities = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: [{id: 1, countryId: 1, text: "NY"}, {id: 2, countryId: 2, text: "Toronto"}]
});
$scope.filterCitiesByCountry = function(e) {
    var countryId = e.value;
    $scope.cities.filter("countryId", countryId);
    $scope.cities.load();
};
```

HTML:

```
<div dx-select-box="{dataSource: countries, displayExpr: 'text', valueExpr: 'id', onValueChanged: filterCitiesByCountry}"></div>
<div dx-select-box="{dataSource: cities, displayExpr: 'text', valueExpr: 'id', bindingOptions: { value: 'selectedCity' } }"></div>
```

More information about the filter operation you can find [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer/?version=15_1#Data_Layer_Data_Layer_Reading_Data_Filtering).

I've create a small sample that demonstrates this approach in action - http://plnkr.co/edit/SR93AIRSp9TUuA5fYmpa

Comment: I'm trying to get some results from MySQL database.

Comment: You have the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined`. And I don't see where you define these variables: `serviceFilterCountry`, `serviceFilterProvince`, `serviceFilterCity`. Also, I think it is not possible to use node js code(`server.js`) in plunker.

Comment: Please look at the code above. I put those variables. Thanks

Comment: I've created a small Express application here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/kif8phwdvvk69qj/ExpressApp1.zip?dl=0 I've implemented filter operation for two selectboxes. Of course, I have not used real MySQL data base, but there is the real angularjs + devextreme app based on nodejs backend. Hope it helps.